How to define variables in case they their values change through a thread?
I have main.py which looks like the following:
...
val1, val2 = None, None
...
thread1 = threading.Thread(func1, )               
thread1.start()
while condition:
    continue
else:
    thread1.join()

#check the values of val1 and val2 after the thread had changed them
if val1!= None and val2!= None:
    do_something()

on the other hand func1 is defined in main.py script as follows:
...
def func1():
    global val1, val2
    val1, val2 = process_something_and_return_values()

My question will defining func1() as I do will guarantee to find val1 and val2 changed and not assigned to None?
if not how to go about this kind of setting to change values of variables through a thread
PS: using Python 2.7
UPDATE: Python doesn't have the ability to change variables across modules. Therefore I want to check if the code is correct if it is in the same module?

When you start sharing variables between threads, you start implementing competitive access protection mechanisms.
But to quickly answer the question, you can take a look at the Event class, and have a Boolean that indicates whether the variable has been set or not.

are you saying that I could change val1!= None and val2!= None with e = threading.Event() e.isSet() ? what about the rest, could it be done like I did?

First question, since you're obviously rather a beginner, why are you using an obsolete Python version?

In addition, it would help if you explained what setting or not setting those vars means in your application logic. My gut feeling is that you are presenting an "XY problem" here and also that perhaps using so-called futures would be a better approach. I'm just guessing though, since there's not enough info provided here for a good advise.

Explicitly define val1 and val2 as globals in function_helpers.py:
val1, val2 = None

... # etc.

Then in main.py import just the module function_helpers and then refer to variables and functions within that module. In this way both modules are sharing the same val1 and val2 instances:
import function_helpers
...
function_helpers.val1, function_helpers.val2 = None, None
...
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=function_helpers.func1)               
thread1.start()
while condition:
    continue
else:
    thread1.join()

#check the values of val1 and val2 after the thread had changed them
if function_helpers.val1!= None and function_helpers.val2!= None:
    do_something()


if they were in the same script, global would have been required right?

we both agree this is a workaround?

Whether the same script or not, the keyword global is only required in function function_helpers.func1 because it is trying to assign to variables that are at global scope.  Without that keyword the function would be assigning to variables that are local to func1. However, if the function only needed to read the global values, it would not require the global keyword because if there are no instances of those variables created local to the function, then Python will look for them at global scope.

Turns out, the way I do it after my update, the var1 and var2 won't be changed after calling thread.join(), why?

You need to update your code with a [mre] that demonstrates this. Let me know when you have done this and I will take a look. For what it's worth, the code works for me.  Make sure you have the global val1, val2 statement in func1.
